# Liquibase not picking up seed data with Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, liquibase

I am using Spring-Boot 1.2.1, and Liquibase to create both H2 (testing) and PostgreSQL (QA & Production) databases.  I have a couple of tables that I want to seed when the db is created.  However, despite trying both dataLoad and sqlFile, nothing is getting inserted. My sql file is just a bunch of insert statements such as:

```
INSERT INTO state (Name, Code) VALUES('Alabama','AL');
INSERT INTO state (Name, Code) VALUES('Alaska','AK');
```

Here is my relevant changelog-master.xml:

```
    xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.3.xsd"
    objectQuotingStrategy="QUOTE_ONLY_RESERVED_WORDS">

...
<changeSet id="3" author="me">
        <createTable tableName="STATE">
            <column name="code" type="VARCHAR(10)">
                <constraints primaryKey="true"/>
            </column>
            <column name="name" type="VARCHAR(100)"/>
        </createTable>

         <sqlFile dbms="h2, PostgreSQL"
                 encoding="utf8"
                 endDelimiter="\nGO"
                 path="src/main/resources/db/changelog/data/states.sql"
                 relativeToChangelogFile="true"
                 splitStatements="true"
                 stripComments="true"/>
    </changeSet>
```

Here is my project structure:
[image]

When I startup my spring-boot app, I can see that the State table is created, but it has zero rows in it.   I also tried taking the  out of changeset 3 and using this:

```
  <changeSet id="4" author="me">
            <loadData file="data/state.csv" tablename="STATE" schemaName="edentalmanager" relativeToChangelogFile="true">
            <column name="name" type="VARCHAR(100)"/>
            <column name="code" type="VARCHAR(10)"/>
            </loadData>
        </changeSet>
```

The csv file is basically:

```
Alabama,AL
Alaska,AK
...
```

I dont' see any messages in the console logs that Liquibase is trying to create or insert the data into the table.  Nor do I get any exceptions or error messages.

**UPDATE**:
If I copy off the state.sql as /resources/data.sql then spring-boot picks up the file and executes the sql just fine. Unfortunately, this means every time I startup, it will try and insert those values again, causing startup exceptions (duplicate key violations)   But, rather than rely on a single file, I would prefer Liquibase to execute them as part of the changeset as data needs change.

Comment: Does nobody else have this issue of the file not being loaded by Liquibase?

Comment: path `src/main/resources/db/changelog/data/states.sql` can't work when you pack your application to JAR/WAR. ideally if liquibase could read files from classpath but can't find it in documentatino

Answer (score 4):

I think there are two issues in your changeset 3:

1. The value of the `path` property directs to a not existing resource. When you define `relativeToChangelogFile="true"` then Liquibase will look for `classpath:/db/changelog/src/main/resources/.../states.sql`. The correct path should be `path="../data/states.sql"`.
2. If the given path is not correct Liquibase should throw an exception. If you didn't get one means Liquibase decided to not execute that part because of other conditions. One of those conditions could be the `dbms` property.  Your changeset should work with a H2 database. It should not work with a PostgreSQL database because of a wrong [type name](http://www.liquibase.org/databases.html). Try `dbms="h2, postgresql"` instead.

After those changes I got a filled table based on your project structure.

Comment: I made those two changes but still nothing happens.  I would think Liquibase would throw an exception if the file couldn't be found, but nothing.  I tried with my states.sql file in this directory location and also in the resources/  (and I changed the path to that).   I am running this in embedded Tomcat so I wonder if there is a way tell Liquibase to just use class path?

Comment: Do you really need the `dbms` property? What happens if you remove it?

Comment: Same behavior.  It is so odd that there isn't any exception, messages, or output in the log about this.  Do you know how to turn on debugging for Liquibase?  I tried "logging.level.org.springframework.boot.liquibase.:DEBUG" but that doesn't appear to be correct either

Comment: Very strange... The property for logging would be `logging.level.liquibase`. What happens if you put 2 additional inserts into your changeset: One between createTable and sqlFile and the second after sqlFile? You should get at least two additional log messages ("New row inserted into ...").

Comment: This is really weird, I get no logging at all in the console or log file for liquifibase with `logging.level.liquibase:TRACE`   All the database logging I see is from hibernate.  It's almost as if hibernate is creating the table ( based on my @Entity ?) rather than liquifibase doing anything.   I do tell spring about liquibase with `liquibase.changeLog=classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml`   Could that be the case?

Comment: So I renamed my `src/main/resources/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml` to `db.changelog-master.xml_old` and I get the exact same results.  I have this in my application.proerpties per the Spring Boot docs: `liquibase.changeLog=classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml`

Comment: Did you add liquibase-core as dependency to your project?

Comment: I was missing ("org.liquibase:liquibase-core") .  Once I added that, then I started getting liquibase erros with my changeling-master.xml file.  Thank you so  much for your help.  I guess I made a bad assumption that Spring boot imported that jar (even though on reading the documentation yet again, I see you do need to include core).

Answer (score 1):

This is because by default Hibernate drops the schema when initializing. So first Liquibase creates the data and when finished Hibernate drops the tables and recreates them according to the JPA entities you defined.

You can verify this by looking for the log record:

```
2017-01-19 11:03:48.692  INFO 15161 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
```

You can tell Hibernate not to do anything with the DB schema by setting this application property:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this when upgrading to spring boot `2.4.1` from `2.2.0-RELEASE` version. The `2.2.0-RELEASE` version had `liquibase-core:jar:3.8.0` as dependency and it was accurately taking `relativeToChangelogFile="true"`. However the `2.4.1` version has `liquibase-core:jar:3.10.3` version which breaks the `loadData` feature.

The csv file I was loading and the `changelog.xml` file were in the same class directory in my case `src/main/resources/liquibase/version2/changelog.xml` and `src/main/resources/liquibase/version2/xref_specialty_codes.csv`

Here is the snippet from my `changelog.xml` for loading the data which did not work with the later version of liquibase

```
<changeSet author="anon"
               id="xref_specialty_codes_load_data"
               objectQuotingStrategy="LEGACY">
        <loadData catalogName="adb"
                  schemaName="public"
                  encoding="UTF-8"
                  file="xref_specialty_codes.csv"
                  relativeToChangelogFile="true"
                  separator=","
                  tableName="xref_specialty_codes"
                  usePreparedStatements="true">
            <column name="id" type="NUMERIC"/>
            ...
            ....
        </loadData>
    </changeSet>
```

I load a hierarchy of change log files with the top one at `src/main/resources/liquibase/changelog.xml` with the following layout.

```
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog" xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.5.xsd">
    <property name="now" value="now()" dbms="postgresql"/>
    <include file="src/main/resources/liquibase/version1/changelog.xml" />
    <include file="src/main/resources/liquibase/version2/changelog.xml" />
    ....
</databaseChangeLog>
```

Comment: I ran into the same problem after I upgrade Spring Boot to 2.4.3. Have you resolved it now?

Comment: i downgraded to old version at that time. With the latest spring 2.5.x versions I do not see this problem.