# best way to read a file in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application that currently runs in embedded Tomcat.  I have a file, states.csv, that I want to parse on startup and seed my states database table (I tried via liquibase but that [refuses to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28964264/liquibase-not-picking-up-seed-data-with-spring-boot)).

I put the file in resources/main/ and that appears to work fine.  My question is, if I decided against embedded Tomcat in the future (say moving to AWS or a regular Tomcat), is this still the best location to keep files for use?

I don't want to code myself into a corner if there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends entirely on how you're reading the file. As long as you're grabbing it out of the classpath, you should be fine. (And I've run single-jar applications on both basic AWS VMs and Cloud Foundry on EC2 with no difficulty at all.)